# Update apps and submit to AppStore by Xcode 5.1 today?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5.1

I have an app built by Xcode 5.1. Now (10/15/2015) can I still use Xcode 5.1 to update the app and submit again to Apple Store?
Because I think I can introduce bugs if I use Xcode 7, iOS 9 to build the app.

Comment: Did you try it first?

Comment: @rmaddy, I tried to install XCode5.1 side by side with XCode7 on El Capitan. But it didn't allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely can, because right this is what iTunes connect says me in the 'Build' section, where you upload your app's bundle:

[image]